# R Programming. Data rearrangement, sum column by the factors of another column

Tags: r

I am seeking help in manipulating my data frame into other format to do some analysis.

What I have now is a big dataset as below

```
Season   Species    Biomass  Abundance
Wet        sp.a        3         5  
Dry        sp.b        2         4  
Wet        sp.a        16        25
Dry        sp.a        2         1
Wet        sp.b        20        40
...        ...         ..       ..
```

What I would like to have is using biomass and abundance as columns with species as row. The cell should be the sum of corresponding column of the corresponding species in either wet or dry season. The end-up table should look like something below.

```
Wet Season
Species       Biomass Abundance
sp.a             19       30
sp.b             20       40
```

Could anyone suggest a way to do such a rearrangement of the data? 
What package could I use. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Season == "Wet", 
    .(Biomass = sum(Biomass), Abundance = sum(Abundance))  , by = .(Species)]
#   Species Biomass Abundance
#1:    sp.a      19        30
#2:    sp.b      20        40
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(.~Species, subset(df, Season == "Wet", select = -Season), FUN = sum)
#  Species Biomass Abundance
#1    sp.a      19        30
#2    sp.b      20        40
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Season = c("Wet", "Dry", "Wet", "Dry", "Wet"), 
Species = c("sp.a", "sp.b", "sp.a", "sp.a", "sp.b"), Biomass = c(3L, 
2L, 16L, 2L, 20L), Abundance = c(5L, 4L, 25L, 1L, 40L)), 
class = "data.frame", .Names = c("Season", 
"Species", "Biomass", "Abundance"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
index = structure(integer(0), "`__Season`" = c(2L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 5L)))
```

Comment: It works really well. Thanks a lot :)

Seems using the data.table is a much convenient and easy for a beginner!

Answer (score 2):

The following should work using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text = '
Season   Species    Biomass  Abundance
Wet        sp.a        3         5  
Dry        sp.b        2         4  
Wet        sp.a        16        25
Dry        sp.a        2         1
Wet        sp.b        20        40') %>% tbl_df


df %>%
  filter(Season=='Wet') %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  summarise(Biomass = sum(Biomass), Abundance = sum(Abundance))
## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   Species Biomass Abundance
##     <chr>   <int>     <int>
## 1    sp.a      19        30
## 2    sp.b      20        40
```